# Contour plot comparison

Tags: cross-validation, matlab, spatial, image-processing, method-comparison

What are the ways to compare two different maps? I was thinking of taking the matrices of each map and then quantify their spatial differences by plotting the map of the differences of the two matrices. Are there any other ways? I'm fairly new to this.

EDIT: It should be known that I have access to all the data in order to plot those maps but I’m not very familiar with cross validation or statistics, that’s why I’m addressing the question here.

[image]

Comment: There is a close vote for "Not on-topic". I disagree, this is a statistical question.

Comment: What you propose is fine - in fact, it is common practice. It would be hard to say more without knowing more details about your data & question.

Comment: For contour maps, I answered this question on the GIS site at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56573/664.  For raster maps, there is an *enormous* number of comparison methods, depending on what you want to compare and on the accuracy and precision of the raster values and their positions.  See relevant threads at [gis.se].

Comment: @kjetil I agree there are (many) statistical questions lurking here--but the topic of comparing "maps" is huge.  Any attempted answer will necessarily be incomplete and rely on a large number of assumptions.  This question therefore needs clarification.

Comment: What about the variance between two data sets used to plot the maps?

Comment: @whuber: OK, but the close message the OP will be seeing is just that the post is of-topic, not that it needs clarification!  This messages needs a huge update!

Comment: @Kjetil That's why I added a comment when voting to close.  We cannot make the automatic messages fit every circumstance.  (I would love, for instance, to be able to name *multiple* closing reasons.)

Comment: I got redirect here from stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253225/contour-plot-comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting the contours side by side is still effective for visual comparison, however, ensure that the colourmap axes are the same, otherwise it's not a good comparison.

Other than that, plotting the differences seems appropriate and a contour map will highlight areas of large differences etc.

Comment: What about variance between the 2 sets of data? Do you think it would be any different that plotting the difference?